# Trying to pass binary files through Logstash

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, logstash

Some process is producing into my Kafka binary files (from Java it comes as bytearray).

I'm trying to consume from Kafka with Logstash and upload the file into s3.

My pipeline:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "my-broker:9092"
    topic => "my-topic"
    partition_assignment_strategy => "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor"
    value_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
  }
}
filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@timestamp", "host"]
  }
}
output {
  s3 {
    region => "eu-west-1"
    bucket => "my_bucket"
    time_file => 1
    prefix => "files/"
    rotation_strategy => "time"
  }
}
```

As you can see I used a different deserializer class. However, it seems that Logstash uses by default a coded that converts the bytes array to string. My goal is to upload the file to s3 as it is. Is there any codec known that doesn't do anything to the input data and upload it as it is to?

Right now the files are uploaded to s3, but I can't read them or open them. The binary content was corrupted by Logstash somehow. For example - I tried sending a gzip that contains multiple files inside and I can't open it afterwards in s3.

The warning that I get on Logstash:

```
0-06-02T10:49:29,149][WARN ][logstash.codecs.plain    ][my_pipeline] Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. {:text=>"7z\\xBC\\xAF'\\u001C\\u0000\\u0002\\xA6j<........more binary data", :expected_charset=>"UTF-8"}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the Kafka Connect S3 connector for this?

Comment: Yes, Indeed that what I'm trying now. As it seems I need to install the whole confluent platform and use their kafka. It dont see a way to use it on top of apache kafka that was installed outside of the confluent platform - but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: You can use your existing Apache Kafka cluster. Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka. You just need to run the worker process, and then install the connector (build from source on github, or download from hub.confluent.io). More details: https://rmoff.dev/kafka-s3-video

Comment: trying to do it, I'll leave an update afterwards

Comment: @RobinMoffatt I guess u are the one that made the video :) First of all thanks for the help. The video wasnt so helpfull for me because I was trying to install the s3 connect on top of kafka machine and the in the video u already started a running container with the services. I download the s3 connect via yum install confluent-kafka-connect-s3.noarch . It isnt clear from the docs, how to start it from this moment.. Any chance to have a chat with u ?

Comment: post a new StackOverflow question with full details of your installation, or head to http://cnfl.io/slack and the #connect channel

Comment: joined the slack and left there a question. I'll leave this question open to see if someone has a solution with logstash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that Logstash is the best fit for passing binary data and I in the end implemented a Java consumer but the following solution worked for me with Logstash:

1. The data was sent to Kafka can be serialized to binary data. For
   example, I used filebeat to send the binary data so if Kafka`s
   output module there is a parameter that is called "value_serializer"
   and it should be set to
   "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer"
2. In your Logstash settings (kafka input) define the
   value_deserializer_class to
   "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer" just
   as I did in the post
3. Your output in logstash can be any resource that can get binary data.

Be aware, that the output will get a binary data and you will need to deserialize it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really understand what logstash is for.

As it's name **log-stash** it is for **streaming** ascii type of files using EOL delimiter to deffer between different log events.

I did managed to find community developed kafkaBeat for reading data from Kafka Topics, there are 2 options:

- [kafkabeat](https://github.com/justsocialapps/kafkabeat) - Reads data from Kafka topics.
- [kafkabeat2](https://github.com/arkady-emelyanov/kafkabeat) - Reads data (json or plain) from Kafka topics.

I didn't test those my own, but using the S3 output option with those might do the trick. If the S3 option is not yet supported you can develop it yourself and push it to the open-source so everyone can enjoy it :-)

Comment: Hey, first of all - thanks for the answer. Logstash already supports kafka as an input - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html

Comment: Hey @JeyJ, you welcome. yes, but as I said, logstash will treat logs as ascii chars rather then binary. I am not sure if the Kafkabeat will give you what you are looking for, but that would be a mor suitable choice for what you are trying to do.

Comment: are u sure that kafkabeat supports binary data? I didnt see in their git page anything that indicates that. In addition, I also didnt see any output to s3 in the yaml example file. The last commit was from almost half a year ago so I'm not sure if I cant trust this project in production..

Comment: Hey @JeyJ, As I wrote, i didn't test it myself. i have just provided you with information about possible solutions to your task at hand. There is always the option to develop your own beat, which can be very quick, convenient and tailor made.